# How to split urlopen by new line Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, split

trying to split sourceCode by new line.

`print(len(splitsource))` returns 1, so obviously the split isn't working.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import time

stocktopull = 'AAPL'

def pulldata(stock):
        fileLine = stock+'.txt'
        urltovisit = 'https://www.google.com/finance/getprices?
        i=300&p=10d&f=d,o,h,l,c,v&df=cpct&q='+stock
        sourceCode = str(urlopen(urltovisit).read())
        splitsource = sourceCode.split('\n')
        print(len(splitsource))



pulldata(stocktopull)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a solution! line 9 uses str to convert bytes to string. Wrong. Solved by using .decode() to connvert bytes to string.

```
sourceCode = (urlopen(urltovisit).read()).decode()
```